# wcf service not getting respose in html page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf

**Code**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3535/WCFService1/Service.svc/rest/hello/Govinda",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (result) {
                alert($(result).find("string").text());
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("hi" + error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am using `wcf service` which is not hosted on server I am just testing it on local server.When i use above code in my `.aspx` page then it is working fine. But when i run this code on `.html` file, it does not work. These both files are inside of my project. So if somebody have any idea about this problem then please help me or suggest me where i am doing mistake.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No i don't get any error.

Comment: Not even in the web browsers console ? Then its weird because you say it works in aspx page but not in html page. You aint using any .net/aspx functionalites it is only just javascript so i think it has to be something wrong with javascript or the loading of jquery in the .html page.

Comment: In the .html page can you test that jquery works ?

Comment: I am getting below error in my web console:- [2:21:44 PM] CHINTAN SONI: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:4102/Service.svc/rest/getData/Govinda. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: What is the version of visual studio you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

**IService.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService" in both code and config file together.
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet (UriTemplate="getData/{value}",ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetData(string value);
}
```

**Service.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service" in code, svc and config file together.
public class Service : IService
{
    DataClassesDataContext de = new DataClassesDataContext();
    public string GetData(string value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

**Web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServBehave">
        <!--Endpoint for REST-->
        <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="restPoxBehavior" contract="IService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServBehave">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <!--Behavior for the REST endpoint for Help enability-->
        <behavior name="restPoxBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:4102/Service.svc/rest/getData/Chintan",
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function(result)
                    {
                        alert(result);
                    },
                    error: function(error)
                    {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using `Visual Studio 2013` and `.net framework 4.5`

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3535/WCFService1/Service.svc/rest/hello/Govinda",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (result) {
                alert($(result).find("string").text());
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("hi" + error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Edit Enable Cors in your WCF service.
http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html

Comment: Maybe you dont need crossDomain:true only jsonp

Comment: I could solve this problem and i am getting response when i am calling service from `.html` file which is inside of of my project.But when i am calling this url from `.html` page which is outside of project then i am not getting response .

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar did you add dataType: 'jsonp' ?

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar do you have access to to WCF codes ? I think you need to enable cors in the service too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have your browser is blocking the request due to Same Origin Policy. Make a try with relative path of the url instead of absolute path. Since your html file is in same project.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/WCFService1/Service.svc/rest/hello/Govinda",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
            alert($(result).find("string").text());
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("hi" + error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I´m sure this will work but when the wcf server is not in the same machine this will not work. as he said he is testing it locally.

Comment: @Tan If he use jsonp, he should wrap the response to a function in server

Comment: I could solve this problem and i am getting response when i am calling service from `.html` file which is inside of of my project.But when i am calling this url from `.html` page which is outside of project then i am not getting response .

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not getting any response from diffrent machine URL is beacuse your webserver is not configured to work with `Cross domain (CORS)`.

To make it work you will need to `enable CORS` on your web server

`Enabling CORS` is as simple as adding this to the site’s `web.config`,

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

For more details to understand how `CORS` works visit following Links:

http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/05/15/implementing-cors-support-in-wcf.aspx?Redirected=true

http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html

http://dhvik.blogspot.in/2011/06/supporting-cross-origin-resource.html